# Can't install django with pipenv although it is installed and identified by the command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, django, virtualenv, pipenv

I've been trying to set up a virtual environment for django using pipenv. I've installed pipenv and configured the path properly. When I run the following command

```
pipenv --version
```

I get

```
pipenv, version 2022.9.8
```

Which implies that pipenv is working.

But when I attempt to install django with the following command

```
pipenv install django
```

I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\Saifia>pipenv install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 620, in parse_executable
    result_version = get_python_version(path)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\utils.py", line 97, in get_python_version
    c = subprocess.Popen(version_cmd, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\cli\options.py", line 57, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 236, in install
    do_install(
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2056, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 526, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 447, in ensure_virtualenv
    python = ensure_python(project, three=three, python=python)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 336, in ensure_python
    path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 302, in find_a_system_python
    return next(iter(finder.find_all_python_versions()), None)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 307, in find_all_python_versions
    python_version_dict = getattr(self.system_path, "python_version_dict", {})
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 115, in system_path
    self._system_path = self.create_system_path()
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 77, in create_system_path
    return pyfinder_path.SystemPath.create(
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 696, in create
    instance = instance._run_setup()
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 247, in _run_setup
    new_instance = new_instance._setup_windows()
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 425, in _setup_windows
    windows_finder = WindowsFinder.create()
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 149, in create
    return cls()
  File "<attrs generated init pythonfinder.models.windows.WindowsFinder>", line 13, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 116, in get_versions
    versions[py_version.version_tuple[:5]] = base_dir
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 367, in __getattribute__
    result = super(PythonVersion, self).__getattribute__(key)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 432, in version_tuple
    self.patch,
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 377, in __getattribute__
    instance_dict = self.parse_executable(executable)
  File "C:\Users\Saifia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 622, in parse_executable
    raise ValueError("Not a valid python path: %r" % path)
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/Saifia/anaconda3/Scripts/python.exe'
```

I've been trying to figure this out the whole day and have tried various things but I'm new this and I can't figure out my mistake.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was using virtualenv for virtualization and had to use pipenv to follow a tutorial and could not get pipenv to work. I had to uninstall virtualenv and pipenv and reinstall pipenv for it to work. I am still using pipenv but I do not like it virtualenv works better for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the key to your problem is the last message in the traceback:

"ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/Saifia/anaconda3/Scripts/python.exe'"

Check and see if this file exists at this location.

If not, your default python version isn't set correctly in pipenv.

Deactivate any virtual environment and check your python version before you install pipenv.